# regex expression for two digit numbers

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to create a regex for Notepad++ for the below expression. However the two digit numbers (for example 24) always change. How should it be the expression?

```
{\cf2 \super (24)}
```

it does not work the following:

```
\{\\cf2 \\super \([0-90-9]\)\}
```

Comment: I edited my question with your suggestion. it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment was incorrect, it would only match a single 0-9 sequence.  This is the right regex:

```
\{\\cf2 \\super \([0-9][0-9]\)\}
```

Or for the general case, anything inside the brackets (as per Clear's comment).

```
\{\\cf2 \\super \([^)]+\)\}
```

This `[^)]+` means "match anything that is not a close bracket `[^)]` (the negate, for 1 or more times (`+`).

Comment: it works, AND how about if I want to include at the regex ANY number or letters that are inside the ( ) , so it includes (3a) or (22:4), and so forth?

Comment: Then you use `[^)]+` to match everything but `)`

Comment: can you write the explicit expression?